# Updating database values after a certain date has passed in Django

Tags: python, django

My site has a section that people can post events with an "event date" field in Django. Is there a way that the "status" field (0 for pending, 1 for approved, and 2 for canceled/expired.) can be updated to 2 after (like 1 day) the date specified in the event date field? The site is designed for minimal maintenance and this would be a tremendous help.

Right now this is just a local server, using MySQL and running django version 1.6.2 python version 2.7.4 I think.

Answer (score 2):

The database values cannot react to time themselves. You can either

- Make your query to take the relative date account (this makes your query little more complex, you need to compare event date field to the current time (`django.utils.timezone.now()`) AND also take account `status` field
- Make a scheduled task which goes through all events and updates `status` if the event date has passed

For the latter approach there are too ways

- Use [a UNIX cron job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run Django management command (no external dependencies)
- Use [a simple Django-friendly scheduled task process like Huey](http://huey.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which goes through all events every 10 minutes and updates their `status` if they have expired

Using a Huey instead of Cron may make your code more simple, elegant and easier to maintain. Using a Cron usually doesn't need additional software which you need for Huey, but requires you to mess with your server settings and your application is less self-contained.

Django itself lacks mechanism for scheduled tasks, as it can only respond to HTTP requests, not time-driven events.